# How can I switch a 12v line with arduino using a p channel mosfet when they have the same ground

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I'm trying to turn on/off a 12v line using a Arduino and a p channel mosfet (f9540n), but if i were to connect them together using some simple schematics online, i would be sending 12v through the arduino. The supplies for the 12v line and the arduino have the same ground since im using the same power supply and a 5v regulator to supply the arduino. What options would I have to solve this? Is getting a n channel mosfet the only choice?

Edit: This is the diagram, I'm not really good at making them, but i hope it helps
[image]

Comment: show the schematic you are concerned about please

Comment: just added it, the power supply is 12V

Comment: What exactly is the 12 volt load?  What other connections does it have?

Comment: its a boost converter to convert 12v to 170v

Answer (score 2):

**Use This circuit.**

Arduino will drive your MOSFET with the help of BJT at 5V safely.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWbK5Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>